# Converting an Image Bitmap to a binary image in Android Studio

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, type-conversion, processing-efficiency

I am trying to display images/video in an led matrix which has LEDs which can either be ON or OFF. So I need to convert any image to its binary (0/1 or true/false) format to feed the values to the led matrix. This is to be done with an Android app.

Can you suggest a fast and efficient way to do it? I am aware of the iterating way to do it, i.e.,

1) nested loops sweeping the height and width of the original bitmap

2) Getting the R, G, B values from each Pixel element and using some formula to compare it with a threshold value.  (either R+G+B > THRESHOLD or the grayscale formula 0.299R + 0.587G + 0.114B> THRESHOLD)

This method works indeed. However, this is very slow. It takes around 2 seconds just to convert one Bitmap. When I am trying to convert a video with multiple frames (and corresponding bitmaps) it takes way too long even for a 10 second video. Another issue with this is that the processor always gets a little choked by the amount of data processed. I get the 'frames dropped' error even after putting the calculations on threads.

There has to be a faster way to do it because there are real-time image filters available in most camera apps.

To be precise, I need a way to take a bitmap and get its binary equivalent.

To save memory it might be better to store the result in a byte stream/array. Otherwise a boolean/integer variable takes up a whole byte each per pixel. And this multiplied by no of pixels in a frame and no of frames just takes up too much memory especially if I try parallel threads to accomplish it.

Hope someone can help me out with this.

Comment: how big are your `Bitmap`s?

Comment: You can use store it in `Buffer` by using [`Bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsToBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)).

Comment: @pskink I am using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap to scale my bitmaps to 358x358 (which is the size of my real LED matrix). Then the conversion starts. So not a huge image. Still it takes 2-3 seconds.

Comment: i have used 1280 x 1280 bitmaps on the emulator and the conversion takes 15-20 ms

Comment: @Shreyash S Sarnayak    What would that accomplish? It is still storing the same Bitmap to a Buffer without doing the conversion to binary (0/1) image right? Er.. am I missing some obvious point here? I'm pretty new to android programming..

Comment: @pskink thats interesting. Did you use the same way of doing it? i.e. iteration and comparison with threshold?

Comment: yes, the same way, both with r+b+g and 0.299r + 0.587g + 0.114g formula, the latter takes a bit longer, 3 or 4 ms longer

Comment: Can you share your code fragment? As in specifically where you're storing it afterwards. Are you updating the pixel of another Bitmap to  255,255,255 or 0,0,0  or storing it in some other form?

Comment: sure: https://pastebin.com/raw/ZweVYWeH

Comment: thanks. Cant understand the whole code, but I got the part that matters. It seems pretty similar. except I used the Color.red etc functions. Let me try programming from scratch again. thanks once again! :D

Comment: I know. I'll post my code soon after cleaning it up a bit. But the core part is the same. I'm storing my result in a boolean 2d array. That could be the problem... there will be multiples of this in my ram when converting video.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a color matrix to achieve what you want. It is much more efficient than iterating over the Bitmap.

The example below takes a bitmap and turns each visible (alpha != 0) to transparent (0x0ffffff) to reveal the view below. Each invisible pixel is set to black (0xff000000). I think you can tweak it to solve your problem:

```
public Bitmap convertBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output =  Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    Paint colorFilterMatrixPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    colorFilterMatrixPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new float[] {
            0, 0, 0, 255, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 255, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 255, 0,
            0, 0, 0, -255, 255
    }));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, colorFilterMatrixPaint);
    return output;
}
```

**Update:**
I've made some adjustments to make the output into a byte array with 0s and 1s (not bit array as this would require some assumptions on the input's size or using if statements that I tried to avoid). I am using two passes and ARGB_4444 bitmaps and that can also be improved to save speed and memory consumption, but it seems pretty quick and most of the work is done in hardware:

```
public Bitmap convertBitmap(Bitmap input) {
    int width = input.getWidth();
    int height = input.getHeight();
    Bitmap firstPass =  Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Bitmap secondPass =  Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas firstCanvas = new Canvas(firstPass);
    Paint colorFilterMatrixPaint = new Paint();
    colorFilterMatrixPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new float[]{
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            1, 1, 1, -1, 0
    }));

    firstCanvas.drawBitmap(input, 0, 0, colorFilterMatrixPaint);

    Canvas secondCanvas = new Canvas(secondPass);
    Paint colorFilterMatrixPaint2 = new Paint();
    colorFilterMatrixPaint2.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new float[]{
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 255, -255
    }));

    secondCanvas.drawBitmap(firstPass, 0, 0, colorFilterMatrixPaint2);

    int pixels[] = new int[width * height];
    byte pixelsMap[] = new byte[width * height];
    secondPass.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            pixelsMap[(x * y) + y] = (byte) ((pixels[(x * y) + y] >> 24) * -1);
        }
    }
    return secondPass;
}
```

Comment: I am somewhat new to android programming. So can you help me understand your code a little bit?

Comment: You're creating a blank bitmap with the same size as the original, and creating a Canvas for that. and multiplying with a filter. But I still dont get the entire thing or how it can be used for converting to a binary image. It might help me get a bitmap with only 255 and 0 which I still have to iterate and do a comparison to get the 0/1 array

Comment: So what exactly is the desired output (An array of 1/0 bits, a Bitmap with only 1s and 0s)?

Comment: An array of 1/0s each of which correspond to one pixel. Ideally a byte array with each byte storing info of 8 pixels (1/0s). i.e., one bit per pixel.